# What are the materials used for tayammum?

Tags: taharah, tayammum

What are the materials used for tayammum? Some days I use powder instead of earth, is that valid?

Comment: You can use your resident wall. Even your wall looks no dist over there. But inshaAllah you can use the wall. Wallahu A'lam.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. yes, my wall looks like it has no dust and i dont find any dust on my hand when i touch it.. thats why i was confused and started using powder thought it could be a similar product. so, are you sure some how that i can use the wall when there is no dust, it'd be more convenient for me when im out of home also. since water doesn't suit me well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only certain materials may be used for tayammum.
These materials are such that when burned, they don't produce ashes.
The easiest thing would probably be to use a rock.

I disagree with the viewpoint of using walls unless the wall is made of brick in which case it is similar to using a stone.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this answer is more specific to my questions!! I didn't know that i can also do tayammum for ghusl! (faound that: For Ghusl one should make the intention: "I am making Tayammum for Ghusl")!

and at last it said i can use stone, wall or Baked earthen pots (Unglazed) when all items which have thick dust on them (mentioned so).. I need more specific answer on this that do the material need dust on it or what if its clean..

And thanks again!