# Can you do Taymmum with stones or other earthly materials?

Tags: wudu, shafii, tayammum

Can you do Taymmum with stones or other earthly materials in Shafi’i fiqh? If not, what does one do if both soil and water are not available?

Comment: If they include dust yes (see https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/52430/is-wall-permissible-material-for-tayammum)